# How to use the Runspace.StateChanged event in c++/cli?

Tags: c#, powershell, c++-cli, runspace

I have been developing an application with `c++/cli` that interacts with exchange online using powershell. I have used `WSManConnectionInfo` class to create connection and create runspace.

In Exchange online the number of runspace is limited to 3.

I have developed a code that currently creates a runspace.

If the created runspace expires due to timeout I have to notify the user.So I thought of using the `Runspace.StateChanged` event in the `Runspace` class.

I have googled but I could not find any example code to achieve it.

Can Somebody help me with this method or any other approach can also be proposed. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the events in Runspace class. But you can try storing the time at which the runspace was created and removing it if the timeout occurs

Comment: I tried but events seems to be a better approach when compared to storing the time

Answer (score 2):

I have used runspaces and built apps around it but I dont believe I have used this particular event. But if all I am trying to check is the status of my runspace object, this is what I normally do.

```
if ($myThread.Runspace.InvocationStateInfo.State -eq "Completed")
{
    #Code to process further here
    #Note that completed only means executed. Does not mean it did not raise errors.
    #For that you can use the Runspace.HadErrors property

    if ($myThread.Runspace.HadErrors -eq $true)
    {
        $ErrMsg = $myThread.Runspace.Streams.Error.Exception
    }
    else
    {
        #Success Code here
    }
}
else
{
    $FailureReason = $myThread.Runspace.InvocationStateInfo.Reason
}
```

Where `$myThread` is my RunspaceObject.

However, I find it hard to believe that the event would be the best way to go. A `runspace` can have multiple states. Even if you manage to get the `eventhandler` for `StateChanged`, you would still end up having to verify if it was a timeout or another. Which will bring you back to the above code where you have to check the `state` anyway.

Comment: You are right but events get triggered automatically whereas your code won't

Comment: I have to definitely use your code inside the event handler.Since I am writing it inside an event,I need not call it explicitly